# What is wrong with the timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm trying to convert a timestamp into a time and date, but I'm having problems even though I've done this before. Here is an example of the time stamps I'm getting:

```
2013-07-22 22:22:55
```

But when I attempt to parse it using

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', $update->timestamp);
```

I'm getting the following errors.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity:
>   Notice Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
>   Filename: parts/update_item.php
>   Line Number: 13
>   A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>   Message: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You
>   are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Denver' for
>   'MST/-7.0/no DST' instead
>   Filename: parts/update_item.php
>   Line Number: 13

Comment: The second argument to `date()` is an integer timestamp, not a character string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtotime` to convert the datetime to unix_timestamp.

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($update->timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set your default timezone using following function.

```
date_default_timezone_set();
```

for more details go to the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Also you should use the following code. You are getting the error because in the second parameter of date function you should put the timestamp value but instead of that you are passing "2013-07-22 22:22:55". [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function will Returns a timestamp on success.

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($update->timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

The date function expect the second parameter to be a numeric timestamp ( like the return value of time() ), the "2013-07-22 22:22:55" string is a string value not numeric and you need to convert it into numeric value first:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2013-07-22 22:22:55'));
```

or in your case:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($update->timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

2013-07-22 22:22:55 isn't a time stamp.

strtotime('2013-07-22 22:22:55');

Answer (score 0):

your first date argument should be Y-m-d

Comment: I picked up on that after looking at it. I had pulled the code from one of my older applications. thanks